# Is NAnt .build file case sensitive?

Tags: nant, case-sensitive

Are the keywords used for project, target, task, function, ... in NAnt build files case sensitive or not?

Comment: What problem are you seeing that makes you think this?

Comment: I get used with the CamelCase in C# so that I feel not very comfortable with reading/writing NAnt scripts which are often in lowercase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this NAnt build script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<!-- test case sensitiveness -->
<!-- ====================================================================== -->
<project name="test.casesensitiveness" default="test">
  <target name="test">
    <property name="foo" value="bar" />
    <echo message="Does property 'foo' exist? ${property::exists('foo')}" />
    <echo message="Does property 'Foo' exist? ${property::exists('Foo')}" />
  </target>
</project>
```

Here is the output:

```
test:

     [echo] Does property 'foo' exist? True
     [echo] Does property 'Foo' exist? False
```

So, yes identifiers in NAnt are case-sensitive.

Comment: I've used your test to try. And I found that not only identifiers but also keywords such as target, project are case-sensitive.
Thanks a lot The Chairman.

Answer (score 1):

In a word: Yes.

NAnt is case-sensitive, even if Windows isn't fussed.